# How to do grouping in Array of Objects in angular 8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts, highcharts-ng

How can I group an array of objects ? Is it possible to use reduce in the following case?

Ex: I need to group id and name if its same need to append data alone into one field.

```
[{
data: ["Sriram Krishnan", 1440]
id: "CHARSUR"
name: "CHARSUR"
},
{
data: ["shaleesh ", 2955]
id: "Timesheet"
name: "Timesheet"
},
{
data:["Balachander ", 3720]
id: "CHARSUR"
name: "CHARSUR"
},
{
data: ["Sriram Krishnan", 720]
id: "Aroscop"
name: "Aroscop"
},
{
data: ["Karthik ", 540]
id: "Timesheet"
name: "Timesheet"
},
{
data: ["Shaju Murugan", 420]
id: "CHARSUR"
name: "CHARSUR"
}]
```

Expected result:
I need the grouped result (data) to be append in array of array.

```
[{
data: [["Sriram Krishnan", 1440],["Balachander ", 3720],["Shaju Murugan", 420]]
id: "CHARSUR"
name: "CHARSUR"
},
{
data: [["shaleesh ", 2955],["Karthik  ", 540]]
id: "Timesheet"
name: "Timesheet"
},
{
data: ["Sriram Krishnan", 720]
id: "Aroscop"
name: "Aroscop"
}]
```

I'M forming data in such a way to use in highcharts pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your source data, please make sure that the object fields are separated by comma:

```js
src = [
    {
        data: ['Sriram Krishnan', 1440],
        id: 'CHARSUR',
        name: 'CHARSUR',
    },
    {
        data: ['shaleesh ', 2955],
        id: 'Timesheet',
        name: 'Timesheet',
    },
    {
        data: ['Balachander ', 3720],
        id: 'CHARSUR',
        name: 'CHARSUR',
    },
    {
        data: ['Sriram Krishnan', 720],
        id: 'Aroscop',
        name: 'Aroscop',
    },
    {
        data: ['Karthik ', 540],
        id: 'Timesheet',
        name: 'Timesheet',
    },
    {
        data: ['Shaju Murugan', 420],
        id: 'CHARSUR',
        name: 'CHARSUR',
    }];
```

This JavaScript code will yield the expected grouped results:

```js
let dst = [];

function getRecordInDst(srcRecord) {
    for (let dstRecord of dst) {
        if (dstRecord.id === srcRecord.id) return dstRecord;
    }
    let newRecord = {id: srcRecord.id, name: srcRecord.name, data: []};
    dst.push(newRecord);
    return newRecord;
}

for (let record of src) {
    getRecordInDst(record).data.push(record.data);
}
```